# Quadratic suborders of an imprimitive quartic order

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, galois-theory

Let $Q$ be an irreducible quartic order; that is, $Q$ is a subring of the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ in a quartic extension $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that the fraction field of $Q$ is equal to $K$. Suppose that the fraction field $K$ has Galois closure which has Galois group isomorphic to $D_4, C_4,$ or $V_4$. Such a field is called imprimitive, since $K$ has a proper quadratic subfield (in the case of $V_4$, three distinct proper quadratic subfields). For each quadratic subfield $L$ of $K$, the intersection $Q \cap L$ produces a quadratic order, say $\mathcal{Q}$. What is the relationship of $\operatorname{Disc}(Q)$ and $\operatorname{Disc}(\mathcal{Q})$?

In the field case, one has that $\operatorname{Disc}(L)^2$ divides $\operatorname{Disc}(K)$.

Comment: You can use the [relative discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant_of_an_algebraic_number_field#Relative_discriminant) to relate $\text{Disc}(\mathcal{O}_K)$ and $\text{Disc}(\mathcal{O}_L)$, then look at the orders.